# Deleting # in url when returning from "in-page link # hoge" without making screen transition

Tags: javascript, html

**1.Click in the page link**

```
<a href="#hoge">hoge</a>
```

**2.Back to top Click in the page link**

`<a href="#">top</a>`

**3.Deleting # in url**

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear however i think u need to delete #from url when click the link i think below code will help you do that

```
  var url =  window.location.href;
   var nurl =  url.replace("#","");
   history.pushState('', 'New Page Title', nurl);
```

Comment: i thnk that helped u if not plase notfy me